# Kotlin: Should a job be passed along with a dispatcher while creating a coroutine scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am doing

```
 private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
```

to create a coroutinescope and using that to launch the coroutines in my fragment.

```
uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            ....
        }
        ....
    }
```

I do a cancel on uiScope when the fragment is detached from window. While creating the uiScope should i be passing a job() as well?

Comment: Why don't you let your containing class extend `CoroutineScope`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`fun CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope.html) is clear on this:

> If the given context does not contain a `Job` element, then a default `Job()` is created. This way, cancellation or failure or any child coroutine in this scope cancels all the other children, just like inside `coroutineScope` block.

Using a job that propagates the failure of its children is not the best choice for the top-level scope. You should instead use the [`MainScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-scope.html) factory function. It takes no arguments and constructs exactly the scope you need. From the docs:

> The resulting scope has `SupervisorJob` and `Dispatchers.Main` context elements.